# I have a bit of a complex question regarding writing code for many variables that aren’t identical but contain the same prefix for each

Tags: sas

Ok so here it goes,

I am working with a dataset containing Minimum Inhibitory Concentration (MIC) values for different antibiotics (About 30 different antibiotics). Each antibiotic has MIC values from different test-types and interpretations for each of those MICs.

Example:

The MIC variables for antibiotic **Amikacin** have a common mnemonic suffix **AMK**

- micmr**AMK**
  interpmr**AMK**
  micms**AMK**
  interpms**AMK**
  micvk**AMK**
  interpvk**AMK**
  micpx**AMK**
  interppx**AMK**
  micet**AMK**
  interpet**AMK**

ALL the antibiotics have variables similar to above (I.e. the micmr, micms, interpmr, etc is all the same for each variable. The only thing that changes is the last few letters that correspond to the antibiotic name)

I am attempting to validate these data, I have a list of valid MIC values for each type of test. Is there a way to write a program that will check all the variables that start with “mic” so that I don’t have to specify each individual variable name?

Comment: You can reference all the MIC variables at once using the colon operator. Exactly how to do your calculation requires further detals. `array _mic(*) MIC: ;` is an array of all your MIC variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a microbiologist, but guessing your variable name construct has lots of information in it.

Variable name construct:

`<mic|inter><susceptibility><antibiotic>`

- `<mic|inter>`

  - `mic` - minimum inhibitory concentration
  - `inter` - susceptibility interpretation
- *`<susceptibility>`* - `<mr|ms|vk|px|et>`

  - `mr` - resistant
  - `ms` - sensitive
  - `vk` -
  - `px` -
  - `et` -
- *`<antibiotic>`*

There are two approaches to validating the presence of MIC related variable names in the data set:

- Way #1 - List a comparison of the data set variables to a constructed list of variables.  The list is based on pre-specified list of antibodies, OR
- Way #2 - Deconstruct the data set variable names into MIC variable name parts. Report on the data set variables and any possibly missing MIC variables.

Examples:

**Simlate MIC data set** - Make a data set with some MIC variable names

```
* simluate some data;
data have;
  do sampleid = 1 to 1000;
    length instrumentid $20.;
    format rundate yymmdd10.;
    length operator $10.;
    array construct_names 
micmrMarbo
interpetamk micetamk interpmramk micmramk interpmsamk micmsamk 
interppxamk micpxamk interpvkamk micvkamk
interpetimi micetimi interpmrimi micmrimi interpmsimi micmsimi
interppximi micpximi interpvkimi micvkimi
interpmsfubar micmsfubar
interppxfubar micpxfoobar
; 
      do over construct_names;
        construct_names = round(rand("normal", 50,9), 0.25);
      end;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

**Get metadata**

```
* get data set variable names as data;

proc contents noprint data=have out=have_names(keep=varnum name);
run;
```

**Way #1**

```
* compute variable names for expected MIC naming constructs;
* match only expected antibody variables;

data expect_names(keep=sequence name);
  * load arrays with construct parts;
  array part1(2) $6 ('mic', 'interp');
  array part2(5) $2 ('mr', 'ms', 'vk', 'px', 'et');
  array part3(4) $10 ('AMK', 'IMIP', 'TOBI', 'TYPO');       /* 4 expected antibodies */

  * construct expected names;
  do part3_index = 1 to dim(part3);
    do part2_index = 1 to dim(part2);
      do part1_index = 1 to dim(part1);

        sequence + 1;
        name = cats(part1[part1_index], part2[part2_index], part3[part3_index]);
        output;

      end;
    end;
  end;
run;

* Way 1 data validation: compare data variable names to expectations;

proc sql;
  create table name_comparison as
  select
    varnum, 
    coalesce(have_names.name,expect_names.name) as name,
    case 
      when have.name is null and expect.name is not null then 'Expected MIC variable was not in the data set'
      when have.name is not null and expect.name is null then 'NOT a MIC variable construct'
      else 'OK'
    end as status
  from have_names as have
  full join expect_names as expect
  on upper(have.name) eq upper(expect.name)
  order by have.varnum, expect.sequence
;

ods html file='compare.html' style=plateau;
proc print data=name_comparison;
  var varnum;
  var name / style=[fontfamily=monospace];
  var status;
run;
ods html close;
```

The report would be a simple listing showing how the variable names were evaluated

[image]

**Way #2**

Deconstruct data set variable names and color coded grid report.

```
* Compute construct parts and check for completeness;

proc sql;
  create table part1 ( 
    order num, mnemonic char(6), meaning char(200)
  );
  insert into part1 
    values (1, 'mic', 'minimum inhibitory concentration')
    values (2, 'interp', 'susceptibility interpretation')
  ;

  create table part2 (
    order num, mnemonic char(6), meaning char(200)
  );
  insert into part2
    values (1, 'mr', '??')
    values (2, 'ms', '??')
    values (3, 'vk', '??')
    values (4, 'px', '??')
    values (5, 'et', '??')
  ;

  create table mic_name_prefixes as 
  select 
    part1.order as part1z format=2.
  , part1.mnemonic as part1
  , part2.order as part2z format=2.
  , part2.mnemonic as part2
  , cats(part1.mnemonic,part2.mnemonic) as prefix
  from part1 cross join part2
  ;

  create table antibodies(label="Extract antibody from variable names with proper prefix") as 
  select 
    substr(upper(name),length(prefix)+1) as antibody
  , min(varnum) as abz format=6.
  from have_names
  join mic_name_prefixes
    on upper(name) like upper(cats(prefix,'%'))
  group by antibody
  order by abz
  ;

  * sub select CROSS JOIN for complete grid;
  * FULL JOIN for complete comparison;

  create table name_grid_data as
  select 
      abz, part1z, part2z
    , grid.part1, grid.part2, grid.antibody
    , coalesce(grid.name,have.name) as varname length=32
    , not missing(have.name) as expected_found format=1.
  from 
  ( select PREFIX.*, AB.*, cats(part1,part2,antibody) as name
    from mic_name_prefixes PREFIX
    cross join antibodies  AB
  ) as grid
  full join have_names as have
  on upper(have.name) = upper(grid.name)
  order by 
    coalesce(abz,have.varnum+1e6), part2z, part1z
  ;

  reset noprint;
  select count(distinct antibody) into :abcount trimmed from name_grid_data;
  select count(distinct 0) into :abmissing trimmed from name_grid_data where missing(antibody);

  %let abcount = %eval(&abcount + &abmissing);

  %put NOTE: &=abcount;

%macro cols (from,to);
  /* needed for array statement in compute block */
  %local index;
  %do index = &from %to &to;
_c&index._
  %end;
%mend;

ods html file = 'mic_names.html';
proc report data=name_grid_data spanrows missing;
  column 
    part1 part2 
    antibody,varname             /* 'display var under across var' trick, display will be shown */
    antibody=ab,expected_found   /* same trick with ab alias, to get _c#_ column for compute block logic */
    placeholder
  ;

  define part1 / group order=data ' ' style=header;
  define part2 / group order=data ' ' style=header;
  define antibody / across order=data ' ';
  define ab       / across order=data ' ' noprint;    /* NOPRINT, _c#_ available, but not rendered */
  define varname / ' ' style=[fontfamily=monospace];
  define placeholder / noprint;                       /* required for 'display under across' trick */

  /* right most column has access to all leftward columns */
  compute placeholder;
    array name_col %cols(3, %eval(2+&abcount));                    /* array for _c#_ columns */
    array have_col %cols(%eval(3+&abcount), %eval(2+2*&abcount));  /* array for _c#_ columns */

    /* conditionally highlight the missing variables */
    do index = 1 to &abcount - &abmissing;
      if not missing ( name_col(index) ) then do;
        if not have_col(index) then 
          call define (vname(name_col(index)), 'style', 'style=[background=lightred]');
        else
          call define (vname(name_col(index)), 'style', 'style=[background=lightgreen]');
      end;
    end;

  endcomp;
run;
ods html close;
```

Color coded grid report

[image]

Comment: Whew! That’s going to take me a bit to process and understand! Thank you for the help, I’ll see if I can make this work.